# Woocommerce order status update from select from frontend

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, forms, woocommerce

I have displayed wc orders in frontend with SQL Select. Select looks like it:

```
 $res = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT
    p.ID as order_id,
    p.post_date as dater,
    p.post_excerpt as komentaras,
    oimi.status as statusas,
    oim.meta_value as qty,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_email' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as billing_email,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_first_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_first_name,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_last_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_last_name,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_address_index' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as shipping_address_index,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_total' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as order_total,                 
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'additional_' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as atsiemimo_vieta,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_payment_method_title' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as payment_method_title,
    ( select group_concat(order_item_name separator ' <hr> ' ) from wp_woocommerce_order_items where order_id = p.ID and order_item_type = 'line_item' ) as order_items,
    ( select order_item_name  from wp_woocommerce_order_items where order_id = p.ID and order_item_type = 'shipping' ) as order_shipping       
    
FROM
    wp_posts p 
    join wp_postmeta pm on p.ID = pm.post_id
    join wp_woocommerce_order_items oi on p.ID = oi.order_id
    right join wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta oim on oi.order_item_id = oim.order_item_id
    join wp_wc_order_stats oimi on pm.post_id = oimi.order_id
WHERE
    post_type = 'shop_order' AND
    oim.meta_key = '_qty'
    
group by
    p.ID DESC");
```

And display looks like this

```
    echo '<table id="customers"><tr>';
echo '<th>ID order</th>';    
echo '<th>Items</th>';
echo '<th>Qty</th>';
echo '<th>Info</th>';
echo '<th>Total</th>';
echo '<th>Status</th>';
echo '<th>Info customers</th>';
echo '<th>Action</th>';
echo '<th>Date</th>';
echo '</tr>';
// Loop through each order post object
foreach( $res as $res ){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $res->order_id . '<br>' . $res->order_item_id . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $res->order_items . '</td>';   
    echo '<td>' . $res->qty . '</td>';   
    echo '<td>' . $res->payment_method_title . '<br>' . $res->order_shipping . '<br>' . $res->atsiemimo_vieta . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $res->order_total . '€ </td>';
    
    if($res->statusas == 'wc-on-hold'){ 
         echo '<td> Sustabdytas </td>';
    } else{
        echo '<td>' . $res->statusas . '</td>';    
    };    
    
    echo '<td>' . $res->_billing_first_name.' '.$res->_billing_last_name . ' '. $res->billing_email . '<br><b>Pristatymo adresas: </b>'.$res->shipping_address_index .'<br><b> Komentaras : </b>'. $res->komentaras .'</td>';  
    
    
    echo '<td>   <form method="post">
                    <select name="statusass">
                        <option value="wc-on-hold">On Hold</option>
                        <option value="wc-processing">Processing</option>
                        <option value="">Cancel</option>
                        <option value="">Completed</option>
                    </select>
                  <br><br>
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                  </form>
        </td>';
    echo '<td>' . $res->dater . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

As you can see, the rendered output has a select form with distinct order statuses. I want this selector to be able to change the status of the order, given that someone selects the status and clicks submit.

I have tried the following code:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $Status=$_POST["statusass"];
    $stmt = "UPDATE wp_wc_order_stats SET status='$Status' WHERE order_id=177386"; 
            echo "Pakeista";
  } 
?>
```

But it is not working. How can I take selected option and order_id from specific tables row where it was selected? It's a litle bit hard to me with SQL and I really lost in it like for month, please help

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a hidden input field in your status form and that will allow you to edit the status of selected order.

You can also get the WooCommerce order statuses using WooCommerce API function called `wc_get_order_statuses()` as defined [here](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_get_order_statuses/).

I have also noticed you are not executing the SQL statement for changing the status. Following are the amendments.

#### #1 Get and Store WooCommerce Status

```
$woocommerce_statuses = '';

foreach( wc_get_order_statuses() as $key => $status ){
    if( $res[0]->statusas === $key ){
        $woocommerce_statuses .= '<option value="'.$key.'" selected>'.$status.'</option>';
    }
    else{
        $woocommerce_statuses .= '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$status.'</option>';
    }
}
```

#### #2 Add hidden input field for Order ID and WooCommerce Status

```
echo '<td>   
    <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" value="'.$res->order_id.'" name="order_id"/>
        <select name="statusass">'.$woocommerce_statuses.'</select>
        <br><br>
        <input name="status_update" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</td>';
```

#### #3 Changing the status once the form is submitted:

```
if( isset( $_POST["status_update"] ) ){
    $status   =  esc_sql( $_POST["statusass"] );
    $order_id =  esc_sql( $_POST["order_id"] );
    $stmt     = 'UPDATE wp_wc_order_stats SET status="'.$status.'" WHERE order_id='.$order_id; 
    $wpdb->get_results( $stmt );
}
```

#### #4 Everything Together:

```
if( isset( $_POST["status_update"] ) ){
        $status   =  esc_sql( $_POST["statusass"] );
        $order_id =  esc_sql( $_POST["order_id"] );
        $stmt     = 'UPDATE wp_wc_order_stats SET status="'.$status.'" WHERE order_id='.$order_id; 
        $wpdb->get_results( $stmt );
}
$res = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT
    p.ID as order_id,
    p.post_date as dater,
    p.post_excerpt as komentaras,
    oimi.status as statusas,
    oim.meta_value as qty,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_email' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as billing_email,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_first_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_first_name,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_last_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_last_name,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_address_index' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as shipping_address_index,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_total' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as order_total,                 
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'additional_' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as atsiemimo_vieta,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_payment_method_title' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as payment_method_title,
    ( select group_concat(order_item_name separator ' <hr> ' ) from wp_woocommerce_order_items where order_id = p.ID and order_item_type = 'line_item' ) as order_items,
    ( select order_item_name  from wp_woocommerce_order_items where order_id = p.ID and order_item_type = 'shipping' ) as order_shipping       
    
FROM
    wp_posts p 
    join wp_postmeta pm on p.ID = pm.post_id
    join wp_woocommerce_order_items oi on p.ID = oi.order_id
    right join wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta oim on oi.order_item_id = oim.order_item_id
    join wp_wc_order_stats oimi on pm.post_id = oimi.order_id
WHERE
    post_type = 'shop_order' AND
    oim.meta_key = '_qty'
    
group by
    p.ID DESC");

$woocommerce_statuses = '';

foreach( wc_get_order_statuses() as $key => $status ){
    if( $res[0]->statusas === $key ){
        $woocommerce_statuses .= '<option value="'.$key.'" selected>'.$status.'</option>';
    }
    else{
        $woocommerce_statuses .= '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$status.'</option>';
    }
}
echo '<table id="customers"><tr>';
echo '<th>ID order</th>';    
echo '<th>Items</th>';
echo '<th>Qty</th>';
echo '<th>Info</th>';
echo '<th>Total</th>';
echo '<th>Status</th>';
echo '<th>Info customers</th>';
echo '<th>Action</th>';
echo '<th>Date</th>';
echo '</tr>';
// Loop through each order post object

foreach( $res as $res ){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $res->order_id . '<br>' . $res->order_item_id . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $res->order_items . '</td>';   
    echo '<td>' . $res->qty . '</td>';   
    echo '<td>' . $res->payment_method_title . '<br>' . $res->order_shipping . '<br>' . $res->atsiemimo_vieta . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $res->order_total . '€ </td>';
    
    if($res->statusas == 'wc-on-hold'){ 
        echo '<td> Sustabdytas </td>';
    } else{
        echo '<td>' . $res->statusas . '</td>';    
    };    
    
    echo '<td>' . $res->_billing_first_name.' '.$res->_billing_last_name . ' '. $res->billing_email . '<br><b>Pristatymo adresas: </b>'.$res->shipping_address_index .'<br><b> Komentaras : </b>'. $res->komentaras .'</td>';  
    echo '<td>   
            <form method="post">
                <input type="hidden" value="'.$res->order_id.'" name="order_id"/>
                <select name="statusass">'.$woocommerce_statuses.'</select>
                <br><br>
                <input name="status_update" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </td>';
    echo '<td>' . $res->dater . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

Notes:

1. These code blocks should be hooked in WordPress properly. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/.
2. Some variables requires escaping and sanitisation. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_sql/.